# Complexity zoo for unary languages

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, big-list

Of course, some complexity results may collapse for unary languages but I wonder
if there is somewhere a survey summarizing the known results in this case: a kind of 
complexity zoo for unary languages. Would you know of such a reference ?

Comment: Of course, it is unknown whether there exists an NP-complete unary language. See this for more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_language#Relationships_to_other_complexity_classes

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for, but here is mini zoo with some languages reducible to unary languages.  http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3282

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no Zoo-style reference yet, but a recent automata-theoretic survey of Giovanni Pighizzini has been useful to me, especially the [slides](http://pighizzini.di.unimi.it/talks/2014/ciaa2014-full.pdf) from his talk.

- Giovanni Pighizzini, *Investigations on Automata and Languages over a Unary Alphabet*, CIAA 2014.  doi:[10.1007/978-3-319-08846-4_3](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-08846-4_3)

Answer (score 12):

One interesting question about complexity classes over a unary alphabet that is not in the above references is the strength of Valiant's class #P<sub>1</sub>, the class of counting problems over a unary alphabet (see http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0208032).  Not much is known about its power, though it has natural complete problems and, like unary languages, has polynomial-size circuits.